# How to remove the two characters after particular point in string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `203.99000` but I want to be like this `203.99`. I tried to put toFixed here but I am using string so it didn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

```
var str = "203.99000";
str = parseFloat(str).toFixed(2)
```

In this case I'm using [.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) to convert the string to a float number, then use the [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function to truncate decimals.

**Method 2:** Using [.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr) and [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf):

```
var str = "203.99000";
str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(".") + 3)
```

**Method 3:** Using [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace):

```
var str = "203.99000";
str = str.replace(/\.([\d]{2})\d+$/, ".$1")
```

The most accurate way is the first, because if you use other methods, the string just is truncated.